# Click button, show div content, hide others - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a list of buttons that when one is clicked it displays that DIV and hides the rest. There is also a default message that shows before any button is clicked.

I've created a codepen already and I think there is something wrong with my script, but I can't work out what I am doing wrong. Any help?

Here is the script I am trying:

```
   <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.div-toggle', function() {
          var target = $(this).data('target');
          var show = $("button:selected", this).data('show');
          $(target).children().addClass('hide');
          $(show).removeClass('hide');
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.div-toggle').trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/simplecreatif/pen/RVbPqa).

Comment: You can always check devtools for errors. `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: click`. Change it for a valid pseudo-class like `:focus` and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it on div click .

Do it by button click:

Just simple code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.map-point-sm', function() {
  var show = $(this).data('show');
  $(show).removeClass("hide").siblings().addClass("hide");
});
```

You can check pan code here:

http://codepen.io/sagar_arora/pen/BRBopY

Answer (score 1):

Change your code

```
var show = $("button:selected", this).data('show');
```

to

```
 var show = $("button:focus", this).data('show');
```

Comment: Actually, this seems to work on Chrome but not Safari... even the Codepen with the change you recommend doesn't do anything in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.div-toggle', function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  var show =  $("button:focus", this).data('show');
  $(target).children().addClass('hide');
  $(show).removeClass('hide');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.div-toggle').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.map-container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-container">
  <div class="inner-basic division-map div-toggle" data-target=".division-details" id="divisiondetail">
    <button class="map-point" data-show=".darwin">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <p>Darwin</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point-sm" data-show=".ptown">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <p>Ptown</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point-sm" data-show=".philly">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <p>Philly</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point-sm" data-show=".dela">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <p>Dela</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div><!-- end inner basic -->
</div>


<div class="map-container">
  <div class="inner-basic division-details">
    <div class="initialmsg">
      <p>Choose button above</p>
    </div>
    <div class="darwin hide">
      <p>Darwin Content here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ptown hide">
      <p>Ptown Content here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="philly hide">
      <p>Philly Content here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dela hide">
      <p>Dela Content here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```